# iOS 11 Vision. Can only perform VNImageBasedRequest 15 times before freezing

Tags: objective-c, computer-vision, freeze, avcapturesession

I am performing a `VNDetectFaceRectanglesRequest` on the output of an `AVCaptureSession`. I am able to perform exactly 15 request each time before the camera view freezes and the output is no longer called. No errors or interruptions are reported. I am able to restart the camera by calling stopRunning, then startRunning, but I am only able to perform 15 more requests before it freezing again. I have tried putting 10 seconds between each request, but it will still only run the request 15 times.

Output Method

```
-(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)output didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {
CIImage *img = [CIImage imageWithCVImageBuffer:CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)];
  if(img){
      runCount += 1;
      NSLog(@"Run Count");
      NSLog(@"%i", runCount);
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
        [self proccessImage:img];
      });
  }
}
-(void)proccessImage:(CIImage *)img{
  if(@available(iOS 11, *)){
    NSDictionary *opt = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
    [[[VNImageRequestHandler alloc]initWithCIImage:img orientation:kCGImagePropertyOrientationLeftMirrored options:opt] performRequests:[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:faceRequest, nil] error:nil];

  }
}
```